# How fill custom class in View in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a few Models, they a group in one just like that:

```
    public class AllData 
    {
    public Category Category {get;set;} // just two string properties ID and Name 
    public SubCategory SubCategory {get;set;} // three string properties ID, Name, Parent_ID
    }
```

and i have a View, if i just do standart fill like

```
   <input asp-for="SubCategory.Name" class="form-control" />
```

they return null, why this happening, all this public, and have set

All view:

```
@model CategoryBD.Models.AllData

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>Subcategory</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="subcategory.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="subcategory.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="subcategory.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="subcategory.Parent_ID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="subcategory.Parent_ID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="subcategory.Parent_ID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(AllData subcategory)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(subcategory);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
        }
        return View(subcategory);
    }
```

In controller subcategory.subcategory always null, even if create just variable like a:

```
public SubCategory SubCategory = new SubCategory();
```

Comment: Have you correctly defined the @model in your view?

Comment: show your html view code

Comment: Use `@Model.SubCategory.Name`.

Comment: They return null where ?Share relevant code and your expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is about the consistency of model binding.
Passed from the view is an object containing two **string type** fields, and the parameter in your action contain two **object type** fields.

Try to make the following code changes

In View

```
<form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.SubCategory.Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.SubCategory.Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.SubCategory.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.SubCategory.Parent_ID" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.SubCategory.Parent_ID" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.SubCategory.Parent_ID" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(SubCategory subcategory)
    {
    }
```

The screenshot of subcategory
[image]